# Solve $y'-2=e^{x^2}y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is for some help. A differential equation $y'-1=e^{x^2}y$, and if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are solutions to the differential equation, then will $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ solve the equation $y'-2=e^{x^2}y$. So basically it's saying 2 solutions to the old equation added together, does it solve the equation $y'-2=e^{x^2}y$. I think it's no. It's 2 solutions from a totally different differential equation! It's combined, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I apologize for hiding my post for few minutes, for I have misread your problem.I edited it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check it

We know that $f$ and $g$ are solutions to the differential equation

$$ y'-1=e^{x^2}y$$

Let's check wether $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ satisfies the following equation:

$$ y'- 2=e^{x^2}y$$
Then
$$ (f(x)+g(x))'-2 
=e^{x^2}(f(x)+g(x)) 
$$
$$
f'(x)+g'(x)-1-1 
=e^{x^2}f(x)+e^{x^2}g(x) \hspace{1cm} (1)
$$

Since $f$ is a solution, then

$$ f'(x) - 1 = e^{x^2}f(x)$$

We cancel the two parts from $(1)$ :

$$ g'(x) -1 = e^{x^2}g(x) $$

Which is also correct because $g$ is a solution to the first equation

So yes, $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is a solution to your second equation.

It doesn't matter from where you got the solutions, as long as the sum satisfies the equation we're all good

Comment: please edit out your \large it's not necessary

Comment: Wow! so it's not right then, my hypothesis.

Comment: Try to keep the first differential equation and check wether the sum still holds. It's not always true, it depends.